# How to disable peel (hover effect) in turn.js?

Tags: javascript, turnjs

I don't want the hover animation in turn.js.
Have tried this:

```
$('#flipbook').turn({
    width: 400,
    height: 300,
});

$('#flipbook').turn('peel', false);​
```

Any kind of help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I used this:

```
flipbook.bind('start', 
    function (event, pageObject, corner)
    {
        if (corner == 'tl' || corner == 'tr' || corner == 'bl' || corner == 'br')
        {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }
);
```

Now, it never shows the peel effect :-)

Comment: Note you can also make it shorter by using `if (corner)`
When using methods like `next` the `corner` argument is set to null

Answer (score 2):

```
  corners = {
    backward: [],
    forward: [],
    all: []
  },
```

This should solve your problem.

Comment: This requires access and modification to the unminified version of the script.

Comment: I went with the other answer and it seems to be working okay. I don't think the script is worth using even if it were free; too bad we are too far along on this project to use something else instead. It's too buggy and unreliable, not to mention the lack of options and the poor UX. Oh well.

Comment: @Charlie please do let me know if you switch to anything else, would like to switch as well.